# over the next week

Tags: meaning, prepositions

a. He talked to her over the next week.

b. He said he would talk to her over the next week.

Do these mean that there would necessarily be more than one occasion of talking? That they would talk more than once?

=====================================

c. I went to her place over the next week.

d. I went to her place over the holidays.

Do these mean that I went to her place more than once?

Comment: You are asking more than one question at a time.

Answer (score 1):

The first three examples are incorrect. Example (a) is especially odd, as you use the past tense ("he talked") with a future time ("the coming week"). Example (b) is *almost right, though.

"Over the next week" would usually mean that something stated will gradually, or incrementally happen during that time period, for example:

> We will talk about it over the coming week.

This could mean that the discussions will be ongoing throughout that period.

If you wanted to indicate that a *single event* will happen at some currently undecided time during that period, you would instead say:

> We will talk about it *sometime during* coming week.

Your final example (d) is idiomatic, but it doesn't necessarily imply that you went more than once - it would be understood to mean that you visit there *spanned* the holiday period.